# Mysql blob image has no dimensions when downloaded

Tags: php, mysql, image, file, cakephp

I am storing a few images in MYSQL for security reasons. When I download the image the file downloads with the correct file size and name but no image is displayed. Also the image has no dimensions when I look at it's properties. I am using cakephp.

```
header("Content-type: ".$file['UploadFile']['file_extension']);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file['UploadFile']['file_name']."\"");
header("Content-length: ".$file['UploadFile']['file_size']);



echo $file['UploadFile']['file_content'];
```

I save my image with the following code...

```
public function image_upload($fileName, $source, $extension, $file_size) {
     $this->loadModel('UploadFile');

     $content = addslashes(file_get_contents($source));

     $file_data = array('UploadFile' => array('title' => $fileName, 'file_content' => $content, 'file_name' => $fileName, 'file_extension' => $extension, 'file_size' => $file_size, 'file_type' => 'image-art'));

     $this->UploadFile->create();
     $this->UploadFile->save($file_data);

     $file_id = $this->UploadFile->id;
     return $file_id;
    }
```

Comment: try to print `$file['UploadFile']['file_extension']` out, what does it return?

Comment: Your question is presenting two different concepts - pulling an image from the database - and pulling an image from the file uploads. Which are you talking about?

Comment: sorry the name of my table in mysql is upload_files so for cakephp you access the data in an array with the model UploadFile

Comment: @DRP96 it returns image/jpeg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are few possible reasons you might be having such

A.  Wrong content type .. you have `Content-type: ".$file['UploadFile']['file_extension']` .. that is worng` in your code

Eg. Files extention formation is somthing like ".jpg" while the content type is `image/jpeg`

B. Your file might not be properly saved which must have lead to the corruption on such image

C. File must have been truncated during upload

D. `$content = addslashes(file_get_contents($source));` .. Don't ever `addslashes` to images .. it would messthing up or get ready  to `stripslashes` when you are loading the image

To know if your image is valid before you download you can run this code

```
$image = ImageCreateFromString($file['UploadFile']['file_content']);
if(!$image)
     Something is Wrong
```

You can also use `getimagesize` to add additional validation

**Edit 1**

**Prove of Concept**

```
$image = ImageCreateFromString ( $file ['UploadFile'] ['file_content'] );
if ($image) {

    /**
     * Check If Height and Width is grater than 1
     */
    if (ImageSX ( $image ) > 1 && ImageSY ( $image ) > 1) {
        $extention = strtolower ( $file ['UploadFile'] ['file_extension'] );
        switch ($extention) {
            case "png" :
                header ( 'Content-Type: image/png' ); // This is just example
                imagepng ( $image );
                break;

            case "gif" :
                header ( 'Content-Type: image/gif' ); // This is just example
                imagegif ( $image );
                break;

            case "jpg" :
            case "jpeg" :
                header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpg' ); // This is just example
                imagejpeg ( $image );
                break;

            default :
                die ( "Unsupported Image" );
                break;

        }

    } else {
        die ( "Fake Image" );
    }
} else {
    die ( "Invalid Image -- Contains Errors" );
}}
```

Comment: A.) My file_extension is actually mime type I need to change the field name in the database. B.)I added my code for saving the file above. C.)I am using a longblob so I am not sure how it could be truncated and also the file that downloads is completely blank with no deminsions

Comment: A) Does the image have valid size befoe you add them ? B) `$content = addslashes(file_get_contents($source));` don't ever add slashes to images ..... its would mess it up ...

Comment: it seems it was both add_slashes and i needed to add more chars in my field definition